# Query for insert with values from a texbox

Tags: ms-access-2010

I tried searching for a simple answer but I get complex threads so..

I have a table named Issues with a field named IssueTimeStart. And the form name Issue_Log.

I just simply to put a button where the value, say StartTime.Text (this is a texbox) is inserted to IssueTimeStart field on the table.

I tried using "Insert Issues.IssueTimeStart VALUES Issue_Log.StartTime.text but nothing happens.

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying something like `INSERT INTO Issues(IssueTimeStart) VALUES (...)`?

Answer (score 0):

That could be:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Issues (IssueTimeStart) Values (#" & Format(Me!StartTime.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#)"
```

or to insert the current time for a blank textbox:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Issues (IssueTimeStart) Values (#" & Nz(Format(Me!StartTime.Value, Now), "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#)"
```

or to debug:

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "Insert Into Issues (IssueTimeStart) Values (#" & Format(Me!StartTime.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#)"
Debug.Print SQL
CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```

Now, study the output from Debug.Print

Comment: Nevermind, I entered the fields incorrectly on my end, now the error message I got is:

Syntx error in date in query expression '#'.

Comment: Study the SQL for errors (see edited answer), or your field is not of data type _Date_ which it should be.

Comment: Thanks man, it works now.

Now a second issue, when I refresh the form, the time doesn't update in MS Access, it only shows the default value of the time when the form was loaded..

Comment: If wish to view past entries and adding new entries, create a form that is bound to the table. There is a wizard to carry that out. Then you need no code.